# make a list of directories by creation date

Tags: perl, directory, dir

I have a list of directories, each with 1 file in them, I need to access the file with the latest date.

Can i make a list of directories by date then take the last one? If so how can I do this, I have seen some questions about sorting files by date, but never directories.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you have a list of directories with single files in them is extraneous.

Ultimately, you just have a list of files with paths (or you'll build one), and then you can [`reduce`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) the list to the file with most recent modified date ([`-M`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(reduce);

my @files = qw(
    foo/file.txt
    bar/file.txt
    baz/file.txt
);

my $youngest = reduce {-M $a < -M $b ? $a : $b} @files;

print $youngest, "\n";
```

Comment: +1 for reduce.  Could you use `<=>` (numeric comparison operator) instead of the `?:` here?

Comment: Nope, gotta use `?:` to explicitly specify what you want returned.  `reduce` specifically returns the result of the block, and that's why you can do things like get the sum of a list using: `reduce { $a + $b }`